# Canvas as ListBox ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, canvas

My environment is windows phone 7.1.

I have the following code:

```xml
     <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Background="Black" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Canvas  Width="200" Height="400"
                    Canvas.Top="400"> <====== This is not working
                   ... Some content ...
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

There is a `ListBox` that has a `Canvas` as `ItemsPanel`.

The `ListBoxItems` itself are also of type `Canvas`. For the `ListBoxItems` I set `Canvas.Top =400`, i expect the items to show with an offset of 400 in the `ItemsPanel`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work, the items are rendered at an offset of 0 as shown in this image (the `ItemsPanel` is black, the colorful rectangle is a listitem):

[image]

Why arent the `ListBoxItems` rendered at an offset of 400?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the `Canvas.Top` on the contents of the `ListBoxItems` not the actual items

When using a canvas as item panel you have to remember that your datatemplated objects are wrapped in `ListboxItems`

```
ListBox
  Canvas <- your itemtemplate
    ListBoxItem
      Canvas <- your datatemplate
```

solution:

```xml
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
     <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="400"/>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: your solution works, but now i realize that silverlight on wp7 doesn't support binding in the ItemContainerStyle, aaaarrrrgh :/

Comment: Nope, bindings are unfortunately not supported in styles in silverlight (yet) 
SL5 has them so I'm sure WP12 or something will too.

Comment: hehe, think I can't wait that long :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your `ListBox`

```xml
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Because you see, the Black Area is the `ListBox`, but not your `ListBoxItem`. Due a "commonly known bug", if we still can call it that, the `ListBoxItem` doesn't stretch, unless you add the code above.